# Connect WEb Applcation with LDAP SQL Server

Tags: java, asp.net, sql-server

There is server1(Windows) where Microsoft SQL Server is installed and this is not managed my my team and managed by some another Team and we do not have direct access to it
WE can connect that sql server from our machine using windows authentication(LDAP).

I want to create a web application and deploy it on another server i.e server2 where LDAP is not installed.
Is it possible to connect server1 from server2 ? If yes what are the possible ways.

Comment: "WE can connect that sql server from our machine using windows authentication(LDAP)." **I** have LDAP on my machine as well. How that does help **your** WebServer? (my point: how is the fact that *you* connect to the server relevant to the capability of *the WebServer* to do the same?)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: Thanks for the reply. Currently we have desktop application for limited users only that is why they are connecting from there local machine, but now we are planning to convert this to web application and deploy it on another server which is on different domain as well.

Comment: Then you deal with the connection once you have a Web App licence for your SQL Server. Your sysadm is the best person to advice you how to configure your application once the setup is ready.